# Flexbox drop down menu position and movement

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to design a header with 3 items:

```
----------
   LOGO
----------  hidden navigation bar
----------
  BUTTON
----------
```

Which then grows to:

```
----------
   LOGO
----------
li
li
li
li
----------
  BUTTON
----------
```

I'd like the logo and the button to remain vertically centered and for all growth/movement to happen downwards from the top of the button/bottom of the logo-container. I've managed this without flexbox, but I'd like to use it so that I can get a better understanding of why this isn't working.

At the moment - unless I put a large height for the logo container - which feels a bit hacky - the menu grows upwards as well as down. I'd ideally like to use `justify-content: space-around` but obviously that attributes some space to the hidden menu.

I feel like flex-shrink might be a solution, but I'm very much a novice at all this, and can't get it to work. Here's what I've got so far:

https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/RMrRVZ

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu--open', 700);
})
```

```css
header {
  background: #808080;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#logo-container {
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 2;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo-container img {
  height: 40px;
}

.menu {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu--open {
  height: auto;
}

#button {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rest {
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="logo-container">
    <img src="https://trellis.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/hidden_meanings_facts_within_famous_logos_cover_image.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
      <li>item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="button">Click Me</div>
</header>
<section id="rest">
```

Comment: have you thought about using "justify-content: center" ?

Comment: yeah, it still does the same thing for me at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any good reason to use flexbox in that case. But to answer your question, the key is the `header {min-height: 100px;}` setting.

With the default collapsed menu, the overall computed height of elements in the header is smaller than `100px`. However it will be greater than `100px` when the menu expands. Therefore, it creates the effects of pushing the menu to the top first and then to the bottom.

Comment: oh ok, thanks - it's good to know why it was acting like that. so you think it's worth removing flexbox and then just adding it for larger screen sizes?

Comment: As far as I see yes, I would drop flexbox to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks. It's easy to get side tracked when you don't really know what you're doing!